# Unable to run Django-rest-framework app with django rest swagger

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger

I have created a backend api with Django-rest-framework. This is my views.py -

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import table1, table2
from .serializers import table_1_Serializer, table_2_Serializer
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated #new token


class table_1_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = table1.objects.all()
    serializer_class = table_1_Serializer
    http_method_names = ['get']


class table_2_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = table2.objects.all()
    serializer_class = table_2_Serializer
    http_method_names = ['get']
```

This is my serialisers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import table1, table2

class table_1_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TasteCluster
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'dept_id')



class table_2_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TasteCluster
        fields = ('dept_id', 'dept_name', 'dept_strength')
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers



router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('table_1', views.table_1_View)
router.register('table_2', views.table_2_View, basename='table_2')


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

This works fine for me. Now I am trying to integrate Django-Rest-Swagger in my project.

I have installed Django-rest-swagger in the virtual environment.

I have added it to the installed apps. This is my settings.py now -

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    #'rest_framework.authtoken',
]
```

This is my new urls.py -

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view
from rest_framework_swagger.renderers import OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Test API Documentation')



router = routers.DefaultRouter(
     schema_title='Pastebin API',
     schema_renderers=[OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer]
)
router.register('table_1', views.table_1_View)
router.register('table_2', views.table_2_View, basename='table_2')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api_documentation', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

But I get error when I do this. 
When I try to run

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

I get this error -

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rahman/Desktop/django_exercise/04project/testapi/testapi/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('', include('getapi.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/rahman/Desktop/django_exercise/04project/testapi/getapi/urls.py", line 14, in <module>
    schema_renderers=[OpenAPIRenderer, SwaggerUIRenderer]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 341, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'schema_title'
```

How can I integrate swagger with my existing Django-rest-framework app?

Comment: 1. If you got an error, please consider to attach it to the question, it will help to figure out what exactly went wrong :)  You can try to use this swagger https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg. I had some troubles with django rest swagger too, switched to the one above, and faced no problems with it.

Comment: Hey @IgorBelkov I added the error to my question.

Comment: It may be the issue described here: https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/694 due to incompatibility of versions of DRF and DRS.

Comment: Hi, did it helped?

Answer (score 0):

```
change you urls.py for rest framework swagger:-


from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view

schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='API')

urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', schema_view),
]


Then in settings.py file, add the below lines:-

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema'
}
```